# If combobox not selected any item enter empty string into Access database

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

When I enter a data in my Access database, if I do not select any item in the combobox, I get an error of null exception. So how can I make sure that if I did not select any items, empty data is inserted into my database?

```
OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + Application.StartupPath + "\\db\\it.accdb");

if (comboBox10.SelectedItem == null)
{
    comboBox10.Text = " ";
}

OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

cmd.CommandText = "insert into data ([Auto Date],AKA,[Phone Number],[R ID],[Related Phone],[Profession]) values ('" + textBox1.Text + "','" + textBox12.Text + "','" + textBox3.Text + "','" + textBox4.Text + "','" + textBox5.Text + "','" + comboBox10.SelectedItem.ToString() + "')";
cmd.Connection = con;

con.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Data Inserted Successfully");
con.Close();
```

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if the SelectedItem property is null, then set a temp variable to use in your query string.

```
string comboBox10Text = comboBox10.SelectedItem == null ? String.Empty : comboBox10.Text;
```

Then use comboBox10Text in your query string.

Edit:

```
// Check if comboBox10.SelectedItem is null, set temp variable
string comboBox10Text = comboBox10.SelectedItem == null ? String.Empty : comboBox10.Text;

OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

// Update query string to use comboBox10Text instead of accessing SelectedItem
cmd.CommandText = "insert into data ([Auto Date],AKA,[Phone Number],[R ID],[Related Phone],[Profession]) values ('" + textBox1.Text + "','" + textBox12.Text + "','" + textBox3.Text + "','" + textBox4.Text + "','" + textBox5.Text + "','" + comboBox10Text + "')";
cmd.Connection = con;
con.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Data Inserted Successfully");
con.Close();
```

Comment: sorry I didn't understand

Comment: The problem is that you are trying to use comboBox10.SelectedItem when you set cmd.CommandText even though it is null. You need to replace comboBox10.SelectedItem.ToString() when you set CommandText. I'll edit to show you what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a null check and change the condition

```
If(comboBox10.SelectedItem != null)
{
  cmd.CommandText = "insert into data ([Auto Date],AKA,[Phone Number],[R ID],[Related Phone],[Profession]) values ('" + textBox1.Text + "','" + textBox12.Text + "','" + textBox3.Text + "','" + textBox4.Text + "','" + textBox5.Text + "','" + comboBox10.SelectedItem.ToString() + "')";
}
else
{
  cmd.CommandText = "insert into data ([Auto Date],AKA,[Phone Number],[R ID],[Related Phone],[Profession]) values ('" + textBox1.Text + "','" + textBox12.Text + "','" + textBox3.Text + "','" + textBox4.Text + "','" + textBox5.Text + "','" + "" + "')";
}
```

Comment: Mark as answer if it has helped